# Using scapy with wifi

Tags: python, wifi, scapy, packets

i've tried to send packet using scapy while connected to wifi, and i got an error about "dnet.pyx". But when i connect to wired connection, it worked.
I've searched a lot on the internet about this problem, but there wasn't any answer for this.
Is there a problem with scapy and wifi? Or is there something wrong with my computer/scapy?

edit:

```
send(IP(dst="204.11.192.171")/UDP(dport=5070)/"hello world")
```

with wifi, the error message was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Tamir/PycharmProjects/SIP/main.py", line 10, in <module>
send(IP(dst="204.11.192.171")/UDP(dport=5070)/"hello world")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy_real-2.2.0_dev-py2.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy_real-2.2.0_dev-py2.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
s.send(p)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy_real-2.2.0_dev-py2.7.egg\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 237, in send
ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__ (./dnet.c:1764)
OSError: No such file or directory
```

with wired connection there was no error

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: You din't include enough information to say. How are you using `scapy`? Exactly what does the error report say?

Answer (score 5):

**Scapy does work on WiFi.**

Notice that if you use a computer that has a wired connection as default (most non-laptops are like this), you should state what interface you wish to send the packet on. usually,

```
"eth0"
```

is the wired one, and

```
"wlan0"
```

or something like this is the WiFi.

When sending, add the field interface that way:

```
send(packet, iface="wlan0")
```

That also works when sniffing packets

```
sniff(iface=“wlan0”)
sniff(iface=“wlan0”, monitor=True) # not supported on every platform, with monitor mode on
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not working for Mac OSX, and other network interfaces cannot be set to monitor mode, so plugging a cable in doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably just a problem connecting to the WiFi, the wired connection is a guaranteed connect, I have encountered the same occurrence and it usually because the WiFi isn't the stronger connection

Comment: is there a way to fix it?